# Check for Feed id in hook_feeds_presave

Tags: feeds

I have a module that is using hook_feeds_presave. I want to only run specific parts of this function based on the feeds importer that is running. How can I check for the ID of the feed? These are standalone feeds and don't use node forms.

Answer (score 1):

Try printing `$source->id` ( even if `$source` seems empty ). This should return the machine name.
It's what I always use.

Comment: please tell exact it works or not.

Comment: The "even if $source seems empty" part doesn't make sense to me, what do you mean?

Comment: When I print the variable $source ( using dpm() function from Devel ) in hook_feeds_presave(), I get '(Object) FeedsSource', but I cannot explore it further. I can't click on it to see what else is in there.


However, by looking through the code of Feeds, I noticed that $source has a property 'id', so I tried printing that. And it works, I can see the machine name of my feed importer when I print $source->id in hook_feeds_presave()

Answer (score 0):

Not tested but I think you can print_r and see yourself. 
function MYMODULE_feeds_presave($source, &$node){
 drupal_set_message(print_r($source,1));
}

Comment: That didn't work - I'm getting an empty object array

Answer (score 0):

```
function MYMODULE_feeds_presave(FeedsSource $source, $entity, $item) { 
    if($source->importer->id=='FEED_ID'){
                # code...
    } 
}
```

$source->importer->id provides the ID of the feed